# How to pass parameters with a default value?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a personal project with React and Next.JS. I'm trying to pass a parameter with a default value in order to don't need to specify a value each time I'm using this function. How can I do this? To understand I want shouldShuffle parameter to be default false.

```
const getItems = async ({shouldShuffle}) => {
 // my code
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to just pass default value to a parameters you can do like this ,

```
 function say(message='Hi') {
    console.log(message);
}

    say(); // 'Hi'
    say('Hello') // 'Hello'
```

But if you are looking for a passing a default value as props to a component try, to define an interface and destructure the Props with the default value in case Props don't have an optional argument passed to the Component.

Comment: Just to clarify, the same principal applies to arrow functions - `({ shouldShuffle = true })`